# phonegap 3.1.0 , IOS 7.1.2 - window.localStorage is reset when reloading app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, xcode, cordova

I am using phonegap 3.1.0 with IOS 7.1.2
When I re-lunch my app - my `window.localStorage` parameters - reset.

I am using this code in my application:
    window.localStorage.setItem("kuku", value).
After re-lunching the application
    window.localStorage.getItem("kuku") retuen null

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check anywhere in code you use localStorage.removeItem(key); or set 'nil' value to key.

Comment: Thanks. I do not use localStorage.removeItem(key); or set 'nil' value to key.

Comment: The same code is running OK on the web.(window.localStorage parameters - do NOT reset - on the web)